# 'docusaurus-start' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows-10, docusaurus

When I type in `yarn start` in `myproject.github.io/websites` I get this error:

```
yarn run v1.22.11
warning package.json: No license field
$ docusaurus-start
'docusaurus-start' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When I do `yarn global list` I get this:

```
yarn global v1.22.11
warning package.json: No license field
info "docusaurus-init@1.14.7" has binaries:
   - docusaurus-init
Done in 0.10s.
```

So Docusarus does appear to me to be installed but I just can't do anything with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing `yarn add docusaurus --dev` instead of `yarn global add docusaurus-init` (which is what https://v1.docusaurus.io/docs/en/tutorial-setup suggests) did the trick.

Maybe `yarn global add docusaurus --dev` would have been better but alas that is not what I tried.